# How can I avoid dropping rows with NaNs when using Pandas `where` method?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, apply, where-clause

I'm running into a problem when using the Pandas `where` method.  Specifically, I'm using the `where` to identify rows in a dataframe that meet specific conditions.  If these conditions are met, the `where` method correctly assigns `NaN`s to these values.  The problem I'm encountering is the case where some rows already contain `NaN` values prior to executing the `where` method.  Instead of leaving these values intact, they are being deleted and my dataframe is altered in an undesirable and unexpected way.  How can I rectify this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

High = {'High': np.array([126.93000031, 126.98999786, 124.91999817, 127.72000122,
       128.        , 127.94000244, 128.32000732, 127.38999939,
       127.63999939, 125.80000305, 125.34999847, 125.23999786,
       124.84999847, 126.16000366, 126.31999969, 128.46000671,
       127.75      ])}
Low = {'Low': np.array([125.16999817, 124.77999878, 122.86000061, 125.09999847,
       125.20999908, 125.94000244, 126.31999969, 126.41999817,
       125.08000183, 124.55000305, 123.94000244, 124.05000305,
       123.12999725, 123.84999847, 124.83000183, 126.20999908,
       126.51999664])}       
Close = {'Close': np.array([126.26999664, 124.84999847, 124.69000244, 127.30999756,
       125.43000031, 127.09999847, 126.90000153, 126.84999847,
       125.27999878, 124.61000061, 124.27999878, 125.05999756,
       123.54000092, 125.88999939, 125.90000153, 126.73999786,
       127.12999725])}        
index = pd.date_range(start = '2021-05-17', periods = 17)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(High, **Low, **Close), index = index)

pos = {'pos': np.array([np.nan, np.nan,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])}
stop = {'stop': np.array([         np.nan,          np.nan, 122.86000061, 122.86000061,
       128.        , 128.        , 128.        , 128.        ,
       128.        , 125.80000305, 125.80000305, 124.05000305,
       124.05000305, 123.84999847, 123.84999847, 123.84999847,
       123.84999847])}
s = pd.DataFrame(dict(pos, **stop), index = index)

grouped = s.groupby(['pos','stop'])
grouped1 = grouped.apply(
    lambda g: g.where(
    (s['pos'] == 1) & (s['stop'] <= df['Low']) |
    (s['pos'] == -1) & (s['stop'] >= df['High']) 
    ))

s

            pos        stop
2021-05-17  NaN         NaN
2021-05-18  NaN         NaN
2021-05-19  1.0  122.860001
2021-05-20  1.0  122.860001
2021-05-21 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-22 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-23 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-24 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-25 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-26 -1.0  125.800003
2021-05-27 -1.0  125.800003
2021-05-28  1.0  124.050003
2021-05-29  1.0  124.050003
2021-05-30  1.0  123.849998
2021-05-31  1.0  123.849998
2021-06-01  1.0  123.849998
2021-06-02  1.0  123.849998

grouped1

            pos        stop
2021-05-19  1.0  122.860001
2021-05-20  1.0  122.860001
2021-05-21 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-22 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-23  NaN         NaN
2021-05-24 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-25 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-26 -1.0  125.800003
2021-05-27 -1.0  125.800003
2021-05-28  1.0  124.050003
2021-05-29  NaN         NaN
2021-05-30  1.0  123.849998
2021-05-31  1.0  123.849998
2021-06-01  1.0  123.849998
2021-06-02  1.0  123.849998
```

The problem is that the `grouped1` dataframe is now missing the first two rows from the `s` dataframe associated with the `2021-05-17` & `2021-05-18` indices.  Am I misunderstanding something about the `where` method or is this a bug?  What's the best alternative to produce the desired result below?

```
grouped1
            pos        stop
2021-05-17  NaN         NaN
2021-05-18  NaN         NaN
2021-05-19  1.0  122.860001
2021-05-20  1.0  122.860001
2021-05-21 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-22 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-23  NaN         NaN
2021-05-24 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-25 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-26 -1.0  125.800003
2021-05-27 -1.0  125.800003
2021-05-28  1.0  124.050003
2021-05-29  NaN         NaN
2021-05-30  1.0  123.849998
2021-05-31  1.0  123.849998
2021-06-01  1.0  123.849998
2021-06-02  1.0  123.849998
```

Comment: when you use `s.groupby(['pos','stop'])`, pandas doesn't include any groups with `NA`. the first step would be to instead use `s.groupby(['pos','stop'], dropna=False)`

Comment: @DerekO Using `s.groupby(['pos','stop'], dropna=False)` did not rectify the issue.

Comment: yeah, that's not going to rectify the issue, but you need to have `dropna=False` in your groupby so that rows containing NA are even considered in the first place. then you'll probably need another condition in your np.where clause to consider NAs

Comment: @DerekO But when I perform the following `grouped = s.groupby(['pos','stop'])` (without `dropna = False`) and then `grouped.groups`, I see that the rows with `Nan`s are included.  So there is clearly something wrong with the `where` or `apply` or I'm missing something.

Comment: when you run your code, you get NaNs in the final result because of your condition in np.where, but the rows in `s` that include NaN aren't being considered in your np.where clause. for example: try running `for _,df_group in s.groupby(['pos','stop']): print(df_group)` to see what your portions of s your groupby is looping through

Comment: @DerekO OK, thanks.  Strange that when I omit `dropna=False` and run `grouped = s.groupby(['pos','stop'])` and then `grouped.groups` I see the `NaN` listed but not when printing via your for loop.  Seems like an inconsistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to fill your `NaNs` with some value that you would never otherwise get such as `-999`. Then these rows definitely won't meet your conditions in `np.where` and will be filled with `NaN` in your resulting `grouped1` DataFrame:

```
grouped = s.fillna(-999).groupby(['pos','stop'])
grouped1 = grouped.apply(
    lambda g: g.where(
    (s['pos'] == 1) & (s['stop'] <= df['Low']) |
    (s['pos'] == -1) & (s['stop'] >= df['High']) 
    ))
```

Result:

```
>>> grouped1
            pos        stop
2021-05-17  NaN         NaN
2021-05-18  NaN         NaN
2021-05-19  1.0  122.860001
2021-05-20  1.0  122.860001
2021-05-21 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-22 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-23  NaN         NaN
2021-05-24 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-25 -1.0  128.000000
2021-05-26 -1.0  125.800003
2021-05-27 -1.0  125.800003
2021-05-28  1.0  124.050003
2021-05-29  NaN         NaN
2021-05-30  1.0  123.849998
2021-05-31  1.0  123.849998
2021-06-01  1.0  123.849998
2021-06-02  1.0  123.849998
```

---

For those interested: initially I thought that `s.groupby(['pos','stop'], dropna=False)` should handle NaN because

```
for _,df_group in s.groupby(['pos','stop']): print(df_group)
```

displays all of the groups including NaN. However the moment you add .apply any rows with NaN are again dropped. For example, none of the NaN rows come through when you run:

```
s.groupby(['pos','stop'], dropna=False).apply(lambda g: g)
```

I would have expected this to return all rows including those with NaN. My guess is this is probably due to the fact that `np.nan != np.nan` so when we use `.apply`, NaN is somehow being dropped.